# "Aktivieren" and "aufrufen"

Tags: word-usage, verb, difference

Is *aufrufen* the same as *aktivieren*?

> 1.Ich werde morgen mein Gmail-konto aufrufen.
>
> 2.Ich werde morgen mein Gmail-konto aktivieren.

Answer (score 8):

There's a difference between both sentences.

The first one means:

> I'm going to log into my Gmail account tomorrow.

So you're going to check for new e-mails or you're going to send one.

The latter on the other hand means:

> I'm going to activate my Gmail account tomorrow.

In this case you have a new account which needs activation first, before you can log into it.

Answer (score 0):

`aufrufen` has two different meanings:

- `jemanden aufrufen` = to request somebody to show himself/give notice of himself. „Der Arzt ruft den nächsten Patienten auf.“
- `jemanden aufrufen etwas zu tun` = to request/demand/ask somebody to do something

The first of these meanings has nothing to do with `activate`. But it can be used as you did in your first sentence.

The second of these meanings is close to `activate` in the sense of `activating/stimulating persons to do something`. In your second sentence, not a person but the Gmail account is activated=stimulated to be usable. Alas, `aufrufen` wouldn't be used in German for that meaning. `aktivieren` would be used instead.

Comment: With other words: aktivieren and aufrufen are not synonymous. They cannot be used interchangeably. They are not the same. And actually I had to read your answer several times to understand the connection you see.

Comment: @Em1 This is a conclusion, yes. But you cannot use my answer and your conclusion interchangeably, because my answer contains some more information.

Answer (score 0):

In context of websites,

- *aufrufen* means *hit*. If its an account you therefore may need to log in.
- *aktivieren* means *activate* as in *complete a registration*